# why google add "index.html" to my wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

in Google analytics I can see that all the pages of my wordpress blog are index.html, but there is no index.html there, how can I fix that?
For example https://www.frenchspanishonline.com/magazine/xxx/index.html, but there is no index.html there! thank you

Comment: Maybe it could helps : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009675?hl=en

Comment: thank you, this page should be interesting but not updated as I cant see any VIEW Column in the menu.

Comment: This article only works for the main directory page, I have this index.html to all my directories.

Comment: The articles said that it works too for the subdirectories. "This also works at the subdirectory level. In other words, once you have entered index.html as the default page, Analytics also treats example.com/subdir/ and example.com/subdir/index.html as the same page.

"

Comment: ok, thank you, I am going to try that.